vue3 can't preview docx file
I have this code
<script setup>
import { defineProps, onBeforeMount } from 'vue'; // Import defineProps and onBeforeMount from 'vue'
import PDF from 'pdf-vue3';

const props = defineProps({
  pdfurl: String
});

let isPdf = false;
let isWord = false;

onBeforeMount(() => {
  if (props.pdfurl.endsWith('.pdf')) isPdf = true;
  if (props.pdfurl.endsWith('.docx')) isWord = true
});
</script>

<template>
  <PDF v-if="isPdf" :src="pdfurl" />
  <div v-if='isWord'>This is a word</div>
  <div v-else>
    This CV format is not supported
  </div>
</template>

right now it handles only pdf format,
what can I use so it can handle dscx format too,
I want to see the doc, not download it
As I am using capacitor this needs to work on the web, Android, and iOS.
I tried using:

mammoth
vue-doc-preview
capacitor/filesystem

but none of them worked

https://github.com/VolodymyrBaydalka/docxjs?tab=readme-ov-file work for me.
